# Installation of tools in Azure virtual machine

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I have a requirement to install tools like Nagios, BigFix and other tools inside an Azure virtual machine once it gets provisioned and joined to the domain. Currently, I have written PowerShell scripts for a remote installation of these tools via Jumpbox once the VM is domain joined.

Is there any other way this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you looked at PSRemoting? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rohit-minni/2017/01/18/remoting-into-azure-arm-virtual-machines-using-powershell/

Comment: When your able to install additional components, I would use intune

Comment: I am already able to install the tools using Powershell Remoting. I was wondering if we can do it any other way.

Comment: Any reason you're not happy with PS? Almost all of the provisioning or configuration management solutions have the ability to automate installs. Examples are InTune, SCCM, Chef, Puppet, Ansible, etc. Not sure if this is the type of answer you're after as you question is a bit vague on the requirements or situation...